# Replace NA in a series of variables by a factor level

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, missing-data, imputation

This is my data, and I want to replace `NA` with "No". I can replace missing values one by one. However, I need to replace `NA`s in `s_1`:`s_4` in the code. Just as a reminder, all of the variables are factor levels.

```
id  x   s_0 s_1 s_2 s_3
1   5   75  A   4   110
2   9   36  NA  NA  921
3   11  13  B   7   769
4   11  34  C   2   912
5   11  NA  C   NA  835
6   13  39  NA  4   NA
7   14  45  B   4   577
8   19  42  D   6   NA
9   20  4   NA  7   577
10  13  28  NA  3   573
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are already existing factors, you can use `forcats::fct_na_value_to_level()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Make sample data vars factors
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("s_"), as.factor))

# Add 'No' as factor level
dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("s_"), ~ fct_na_value_to_level(.x, "No")))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
      id     x s_0   s_1   s_2   s_3  
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1     1     5 75    A     4     110  
 2     2     9 36    No    No    921  
 3     3    11 13    B     7     769  
 4     4    11 34    C     2     912  
 5     5    11 No    C     No    835  
 6     6    13 39    No    4     No   
 7     7    14 45    B     4     577  
 8     8    19 42    D     6     No   
 9     9    20 4     No    7     577  
10    10    13 28    No    3     573
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and it was great. You might can help me with this one.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095558/replace-na-in-a-series-of-variables-with-different-types-of-missing

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you need to include `"No"` as factor level before turning `NA`'s to `"No"`.

```
cols <- grep('s_\\d+', names(df))

df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) {
  levels(x) <- c(levels(x), 'No')
  x[is.na(x)] <- 'No'
  x
})

df
#   id  x s_0 s_1 s_2 s_3
#1   1  5  75   A   4 110
#2   2  9  36  No  No 921
#3   3 11  13   B   7 769
#4   4 11  34   C   2 912
#5   5 11  No   C  No 835
#6   6 13  39  No   4  No
#7   7 14  45   B   4 577
#8   8 19  42   D   6  No
#9   9 20   4  No   7 577
#10 10 13  28  No   3 573
```